Integral of geodesic curvature in the Gauß-Bonnet theorem - question about notation
Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$, $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ be a unit-speed curve on a Riemannian manifold $M$ of dimension $2$ and assume that $\gamma$ is sufficiently smooth. The geodesic curvature $\kappa$ of $\gamma$ is then defined as
$$\kappa(t):=\langle\nabla_t \gamma'(t), N(t) \rangle$$
where $\nabla_t$ is the covariant derivative of vector fields along $\gamma$ and $N(t)$ is a suitable unit normal vector attached to $\gamma'(t)$.
In various formulations of the Gauß-Bonnet theorem (for example in "Riemannian Manifolds - An Introduction to Curvature" by Lee), the following integral of $\kappa$ appears:
$$\int_{\gamma} \kappa \; d s\text{.}\tag{$*$}$$
My Question: What exactly is the meaning of this integral?
My problem is that $\kappa$ is defined on $[a,b]$ but not on the image of $\gamma$ in $M$. So it makes no sense to understand the integral as
$$\int_{\gamma} \kappa \; d s \; = \; \int_a^b \kappa(\gamma(t))\lVert \gamma'(t)\rVert \; d t$$
which is in fact the only type of curve integral I am aware of. (This definition of $ds$-integrals is also given in the book by Lee mentioned above.)
I also have access to other expositions of Gauß-Bonnet where the integral
$$\int_a^b \kappa(t) dt$$
is used instead of ($*$). Here the meaning is of course clear to me. I am still wondering about the integral ($*$) since it occurs so frequently in the literature without further explanations. Therefore my question.

I think in this case $\int\limits_\gamma \kappa ds$ really is just a short hand notation for $\int\limits_a^b \kappa(t) dt$, since as you said, $\kappa$ is not defined on $M$, but rather on $[a,b]$.

One way to figure this out is that the relevant integral appears when applying Stokes' Theorem to the integral of Gauss curvature on a surface with boundary. The formula for the boundary term in Stokes' theorem and the definition of geodesic curvature tells you exactly what the integral has to be.

The point is to understand the integral as giving an invariant of the curve $\gamma$, not something dependent on a particular parametrization.
